# Different types of segmentation faults in Linux

Tags: linux, dep, debugging

In Linux, when the NX-bit triggers the segmentation fault seems to be "error 15", whereas a more typical error, such as attempting to read from invalid memory, results in "error 7", (seen from dmesg output).

What other error codes exist? Where are these error codes defined, and what is their true meaning?

I'd like to see a full list so that when I do get a segmentation fault, I'm able to get some hints about what the reason is. I'm not sure how useful this really is, but I'd still like to know.

Comment: This might be better suited for [so].

Answer (score 1):

According to [a similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179403/how-do-you-read-a-segfault-kernel-log-message), the error codes are architecture specific. The codes should be documented in `arch/*/mm/fault.c` as part of the kernel source code.